# Object method does not receive variadic parameters

Tags: syntax, autohotkey, variadic-functions

This works.

```
string = <div>foo</div><br /><div>bar</div><br />
ModifyText(string, {"<br\s\/?>": "REPLECED`r`n", "<div>": "<p>", "</div>": "</p>"}*)
msgbox % string
ModifyText(ByRef strHaystack, oParams*) {
    for k, v in oParams 
        strHaystack := RegexReplace(strHaystack, k, v)
}
```

However, when I do the same thing with a class method, it fails. The class method does not receive the passed object.

```
string = <div>foo</div><br /><div>bar</div><br />
o := new ByrefTest
o.ModifyText(string, {"<br\s\/?>": "REPLECED`r`n", "<div>": "<p>", "</div>": "</p>"}*)
msgbox % string
class ByrefTest 
{
    ModifyText(ByRef strHaystack, oParams*) {
        for k, v in oParams 
            strHaystack := RegexReplace(strHaystack, k, v)      
    }
}
```

Why is it?

The manual seems to imply something.

> This syntax cannot be used when setting properties of objects, since
>   the last physical parameter is actually the value being assigned.

But it does not sound like it's about this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says:

> The array of parameters may contain named items when directly calling a user-defined function.

The implication is that named items/parameters are **not** supported in other situations.

When you directly call the user-defined variadic function `ModifyText`, the named items (`"<br\s\/?>"`, `"<div>"` and `"</div>"`) are copied into `oParams`. Note that the object itself is not passed to the function.

When you indirectly call the `ByrefTest.ModifyText` function by invoking the `o` object, only numbered items within the array are used (but there aren't any in this case). The named items are ignored.